# wait for image to load after ajax

Tags: jquery, image, wait

I'm trying to find the height of an image which is loaded via an AJAX call, but am getting random results.

Sometimes, I get the correct image height and sometimes I get 0 for the image height.

Here is my code

```
$('.content').fadeOut();

$.post('ajax.php?vno=' + new Date().getTime(), {
  action: 'render'
}, function (res) {

  $('.content').html(res.html);
  var images = $('.content img');
  var nimages = images.length;

  if (nimages == 0) {
    $('.content').fadeIn();
  } else {
    images.load(function () {
      nimages--;
      if (nimages == 0) {
        $('.content').fadeIn();
      }
    }).each(function () {
      if (this.complete) $(this).load();
    });
  }

  $('#image-main').load(function () {
    if ($('#image-main').length) $('#wrapper').append('<span>' + $('#image-main').height() + '</span>');
  });

}, 'json');
```

The AJAX call returns HTML for the page in variable res.html, which I move in to a div with the class 'content'.
I then have a section of code that waits until the images are loaded before it fades 'content' in.
This seems to work fine.

The last bit is the bit I'm having a probem with.
The image I'm interested in has the id 'image-main', so I'm using `.load` which I thought would only fire once the image has been loaded fully?

Sometimes I get this code appended `<span>0</span>`, and sometimes I correctly get `<span>546</span>`.

Can you see what I'm doing wrong? I've been trying different methods for hours but they all seem to give random results

Comment: Try using lazy loader for the image it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks rrugbys but Lazy Loader delays loading of images...I want to load the image then get the height of that image.